# How to get suitable CGImage from combined TIFF for display scale

Tags: objective-c, macos, retina-display, nsimage

I have two PNGs in a Mac project. Normal and @2x. Xcode combines these into a single TIFF with the @2x being at index 0 and the @1x at index 1.

What is the suggested approach to get the appropriate image as CGImageRef version (for use with Quartz) for the current display scale?

I can get the image manually via CGImageSource:

```
NSBundle *mainBundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
NSURL *URL = [mainBundle URLForResource:@"Canvas-Bkgd-Tile" withExtension:@"tiff"];

CGImageSourceRef source = CGImageSourceCreateWithURL((__bridge CFURLRef)(URL), NULL);
_patternImage = CGImageSourceCreateImageAtIndex(source, 1, NULL);  // index 1 is @1x, index 0 is @2x
CFRelease(source);
```

I also found this to be working, but I am not certain that this will return the Retina version on a Retina display:

```
NSImage *patternImage = [NSImage imageNamed:@"Canvas-Bkgd-Tile.tiff"];
_patternImage = [patternImage CGImageForProposedRect:NULL context:nil hints:nil];
CGImageRetain(_patternImage); // retain image, because NSImage goes away
```

An acceptable answer to this question either provides a solution how to get the CGImage suitable from a combined multi-resolution TIFF, or explains why the second approach here is working. Or what changes are required.

Comment: Have you tried using [[NSScreen mainScreen] backingScaleFactor] ? Obviously this will only give you the scale factor of the "main screen" (the one with keyboard focus), but might be enough for you to determine which image you need. Alternatively I guess you could iterate over all of the screens and detect whether any of them have a scale factor of > 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am opting to answer on "why the second approach here is working".

In one of the WWDC videos published since 2010, they said that :

**+[NSImage imageNamed:]** chooses the best image representation object available for the current display.

So chances are that you are calling this class method from within a locked focus context (e.g. within a **drawRect:** method or similar), or maybe you actually called lockFocus yourself. Anyway, the result is that you get the most suitable image. But only when calling **+[NSImage imageNamed:]**.

EDIT: Found it here:
http://adcdownload.apple.com//wwdc_2012/wwdc_2012_session_pdfs/session_213__introduction_to_high_resolution_on_os_x.pdf

Search for the keyword "best" in the slides: "NSImage automatically chooses best representation […]".

So, your second version will return the Retina version on a Retina display, you can be certain of it, it is advertised in the documentation[*].

[*] This will only work if you provide valid artwork.

Comment: @Cocoanetics by valid artwork, I mean that your artwork must contain both normal and retina versions. Then, using +[NSImage imageNamed:] will always load the most suitable representation.